# Comparing Converting ISO8601-compliant date with Java date?

Tags: java, date, solr

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date), I have found how to parse the Solr date, but I am still unable to compare it with Java date.

```
DateTimeFormatter parser2 = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
    String jtdate = "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00";
    System.out.println(parser2.parseDateTime(jtdate));
```

Currently I have got date in this format :  2013-07-28T13:48:02Z and I need to apply compareTo() operator on this date with current date from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not care about the time, consider using [`DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#getDateOnlyInstance%28%29), which is a `Comparator` that ignores the time fields when making the comparison, e.g.:

```
final DateTime a = parser2.parseDateTime(jtdate);
final Date b = new Date();

DateTimeComparator comparator = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance();
comparator.compare(a, b);
```

Or,

```
comparator.compare(a, DateTime.now());
```